# What is the default Swagger UI URL in Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am investigating a web app and I can see the API URL via the dev-tools (network calls), but I do not know the Swagger UI URL for this API. It is probably a C# API. What is the default Swagger UI URL?

UPDATE:

It is specifically Swashbuckle.

Comment: http://<host ip address>:6050/index.html

Comment: I tried that and got 404

Comment: Swat library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: @Helen i dont know, this is not my implementation

Comment: Swagger UI path varies based on the programming language and framework (.NET/Swashbuckle, Java/Springfox, Python Flask, etc.). Not all APIs expose a Swagger UI page. It's possible that the API in question doesn't have it.

Comment: You are right, but what I needed is the default URL. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use http://hostipaddress:6050/***swagger***

This will automatically redirect you to
http://hostipaddress:6050/***swagger***/index.html

Comment: thank you @Edd, /swagger is indeed the default swagger/Swashbuckle URL. So I mark the answer accepted, although in my case, the API I am looking into does not utilize this.. they have probably changed it to something else